# getting Error Incompatable Docker With Ubuntu

Tags: docker

I am trying to install Docker on ubuntu-18.04-bionic on a Laptop.
I installed it following this guide:[docker installation guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-and-use-docker-on-ubuntu-18-04).
I was successful with all the steps until I stumbled over the last step.

```
sudo systemctl status docker
```

the output was:

```
● docker.service - Docker Application Container Engine
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/docker.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2019-12-26 09:27:14 CET; 23min ago
     Docs: https://docs.docker.com
 Main PID: 1591 (dockerd)
    Tasks: 10
   CGroup: /system.slice/docker.service
           └─1591 /usr/bin/dockerd -H fd:// --containerd=/run/containerd/containerd.sock

Dez 26 09:27:11 user dockerd[1591]: time="2019-12-26T09:27:11.166888465+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup rt runtim
Dez 26 09:27:11 user dockerd[1591]: time="2019-12-26T09:27:11.166904414+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio wei
Dez 26 09:27:11 user dockerd[1591]: time="2019-12-26T09:27:11.166920490+01:00" level=warning msg="Your kernel does not support cgroup blkio wei
Dez 26 09:27:11 user dockerd[1591]: time="2019-12-26T09:27:11.168505695+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: start."
Dez 26 09:27:12 user dockerd[1591]: time="2019-12-26T09:27:12.718206251+01:00" level=info msg="Default bridge (docker0) is assigned with an IP 
Dez 26 09:27:12 user dockerd[1591]: time="2019-12-26T09:27:12.926480973+01:00" level=info msg="Loading containers: done."
Dez 26 09:27:14 user dockerd[1591]: time="2019-12-26T09:27:14.291990765+01:00" level=info msg="Docker daemon" commit=633a0ea838 graphdriver(s)=
Dez 26 09:27:14 user dockerd[1591]: time="2019-12-26T09:27:14.328054913+01:00" level=info msg="Daemon has completed initialization"
Dez 26 09:27:14 user dockerd[1591]: time="2019-12-26T09:27:14.844127498+01:00" level=info msg="API listen on /var/run/docker.sock"
Dez 26 09:27:14 user systemd[1]: Started Docker Application Container Engine.
~
```

I have tried to google that error and apparently it has something to do with the kernel not being up to date. This result was based on this websites: [a solution?](https://wiki.debian.org/HowToUpgradeKernel)

When I reached the step of installing the latest image,

```
 $ sudo apt-get install linux-image-flavour
```

I receive this error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-flavour
```

I dont have any idea what to do now. And I havent found a solution of how to install the image or upgrade it (if thats the next step).
Also I did a hard- and software specification. My actual kernel is above 4.9. Plus my graphics card is an Intel Device 3185. If that helps.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Please kindly upgrade your system with the command `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade` and try again

Comment: hi george, I run `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade` command on daily basis. But just incase I did your version. Nothing has changed sofar. When I ran the command `sudo apt-get install linux-image-flavour` I still get the error:  `Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package linux-image-flavour`